React video player causing issues on the onPause event. It glitches with the seek bar of the video
I'm encountering an issue with the React video player where the onPause event works fine for pausing the video, but it causes glitches with the seek bar functionality. Specifically, if I try to forward or rewind the video using the seek bar, it pauses the video instead of seeking.
Also if anyone can tell me how to autoplay the video when it is loaded that would help me a lot since I have to make the video autoplay instead of making the user click on the button to play it.
NOTE: If I use the onSeek event and pass setVideoPause(false), the seek bar works fine. However, there is flickering in the video player. I believe this is logical because it first sets videopause to true to pause, and then with the onSeek event, it sets videopause to false.
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import replay_icon from "../src/assets/replay_icon.png";

const VideoPlayer = ({ url, cb, videopause, setVideoPause }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${videopause ? "sm:w-[70%] sm:ml-10 md:ml-0 md:w-[50%]" : "sm:w-[55%] md:w-[58%]"} rounded-lg relative flex `}>
        <ReactPlayer
          className="react-player"
          auto
          url={url}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          controls={videopause ? false : true}
          playing={!videopause}
          onEnded={cb}
          onPause={() => setVideoPause(true)}
          // If i try to use onSeek={()=> setVideoPause(false)} it works fine but there is flickering with the video while seeking.
        />
        {videopause && (
          <>
            <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-black opacity-30 rounded-3xl"></div>
            <img
              src={replay_icon}
              alt="replay_icon"
              className="absolute w-8"
              style={{
                top: "50%",
                left: "50%",
                transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              }}
              onClick={() => setVideoPause(false)}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

I'm actually reducing the width of the video player and aligning it to the start of the div when it's paused, and when it's playing, I increase its width and center-align it.
